# file input does not submit in IE9

Tags: html, forms, internet-explorer-9

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="/page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >   
            <input type="file" name="photo" />      
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit"  value="verder" />             
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

page.php

```
error_log(__LINE__);
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $image) {               

$tmp_name = $image['tmp_name'];
$rand = rand(10000, 99999);

$name = 'id_scan_'.$dossier_id.'_'.substr(md5($rand), 17, 5);               

$dimensions['max_width'] = '800';
$dimensions['max_height'] = '800';
$image_type = strrchr($image["name"], ".");
Helper_Image::image_scale_and_save($tmp_name, $image_type, "$uploads_dir/$dossier_id/$name", $dimensions);

            $post_to_save[$key] = $name. $image_type;
        }
```

This is just a simple form for uploading a picture.
In IE9 nothing happens. The input box is emptied and form does not submit. 
Do I have to look for a server setting or something?

Comment: Could you post the relevant PHP (**not** including your database credentials, of course)?

Comment: well, its not reaching the php page. I have put error_logs everywhere, nothing is showing. But here is it anyway:

Comment: Could you edit your post to include that? Seeing that in a single block in a comment makes it borderline illegible.

Comment: yes I am trying to add an extra codeblock ;-)

Comment: Just found out that when I keep pressing the button eventually the form is submiited. After third click on submit button to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

@Bart So far as the issue with submitting form is concerned, I was also looking for something similar some time ago and found the code given below:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){....}
```

Write it on the same page where the HTML form is present. When you click on Submit button, the **IF** given above will check if the form is submitted or not. If it is, then it will execute the code that you will write inside **IF**. Hope this will solve your problem.

And regarding uploading, whenever I need, I use [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/06/image-upload-and-cropping-with-php-and.html). long with uploading, it also provides image cropping.